# Getting AbstractController::DoubleRenderError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
def purchase
 ...
 perform_payment_post
 redirect_to :action => 'billing'
 ...
end

  def perform_payment_post
    params[:coverages] ||= {}      
    params[:customer][:coverage_addon] = (params[:coverages].collect { |k,v| k }).join(', ')
    params[:customer][:coverage_ends_at] = 1.year.from_now
    Rails.logger.info("--- id = #{cookies.signed[:incomplete_gaq_customer_id]}")
    id = cookies.signed[:incomplete_gaq_customer_id]
    return redirect_to :action => @is_affiliate_user ? 'affiliate':'quote' if id.nil?
    @customer = Customer.find(cookies.signed[:incomplete_gaq_customer_id])
    return redirect_to :action => 'please_call' if @customer.status_id != 0
    @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
    @customer.notes.create({ :notes_text => @note }) if @note
    if params[:property_id].to_i == 0 then @customer.properties.create(params[:property]) end
  end
```

Getting Error on purchase method on line redirect_to :action => "billing".

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return early in controller you either need to write it like this

```
redirect_to(:action => @is_affiliate_user ? 'affiliate':'quote') and return if id.nil?
```